# How to disabled button after user have clicked the button before in asp.net using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am currently creating a seat reservation system. In my system, if user select Seat 1 and proceed till the end, when the system come back again (I have a button linked to first page from the last page), the Seat 1 should be disabled and cannot be chose already. But somehow my code still allows it to choose. Why is that?

I am using this code:

```
if (seat1 == "Reserved")
    {
        ImageButton1.ImageUrl = "seatreserved.png";
        ImageButton1.Enabled = false;
    }
```

The image does change so I know the value "Reserved" had successfully passed to this page. But somehow the ImageButton1.Enabled = false; did not work.
Please help, thank you.

Comment: Looks like you should learn how to write clean code. Use an enum instead of a string "Reserved". And please don't make one variable per car you have. You should have a list and work against a database or something like that.

Comment: hmm I'm quite a beginner so my skill is not there yet I think. I make 1 variable per car is because I have to show a seating chart, with user click the button the image change, so i have to do different variable with that based on my knowledge... Anyhow thanks for the advice! @etalon11

Answer (score 1):

You are not saving the state of your actions anywhere at least you don't explain it. When you reserve a seat in your app save the value of the seat in some source-> db xml or whatever you like. After that on the next opening of your app load the reserved seats from this source and make disable this buttons.

If you use DB and you have two tables Event and Reserving seats. When you click on the button you are inserting data in Reserving with EventID='The ID of Event' and SeatNumber the number of the seat.

After that when you go into this event again load the data from Reserving table for this Event and disable what is needed.

Comment: I am passing the status "Reserved" using the Session method and saving it into "seat1" variable.

Comment: @Acetamide Session is browser dependable, when another user goes into your application your session variable will be null for him. You should use database.

Comment: But our lecturer tell us not to use database, or only use database to store the customer information, should I not use Session ?

Comment: In real life you can't use session for this operation. If your teacher want to do it with session, he probably things that it is too complicated for you to use database, but this app will be invalid and not working properly if you are using session. If you work in one browser session you will not have any problems, but if you reserve your seats and close the browser and open it again the reservation is gone.

Comment: Yes I have notice that too, but I have asked my lecturer and he said the reservation will gone for sure, so I guess he had no problem with that.

Answer (score 0):

try to clean project and rebuild again.. if problem still occurs then try to add new control and implement code again. Sometimes these kind of things happen in .Net Framework.

Comment: may be your image button stuck inside the layout. Its better to find it and Enabled it.

Comment: how to check that, may I ask ?

Comment: Lets say Image button in inside a ListView then you need to exactly point the ImageButton control

Comment: Example : ImageButton b = (ImageButton)ListViewID.FindControl("YourImageButtonID");
b.Visible = false;